# grails actionSubmit url

Tags: forms, grails, submit

I'm trying out the grails action submit button, and I have the following code

```
<g:form name="sample" controller="person">
  <g:actionSubmit value="Submit me" action="Update"/>
</g:form>
```

While it is invoking the "Update" action, the url remains `http://myapp/person/list` rather than actually showing the action being applied (in this case Update). This is confusing from an end user perspective. Is there a way to actually show the correct URL?

Comment: An easy work around would be by just adding the action parameter in your g:form tag, you don't have to change anything else, all you have to do is add 'action="update"' in your <g:form> tag

Comment: Unless there were multiple submit buttons (which seems to be the purpose of actionSubmit, otherwise I could just use g:form action)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually reported as a bug (minor). I don't think it's a big deal not to show the correct url but I agree with you that, depending on the case, it can be confusing. But anyway, the last comment on the Jira issue describes a workaround that works. =) It's basically using:

```
<g:actionSubmit class="update" onclick="this.form.action='${createLink(action:'update')}';" value="Update" />
```

Here's the [link](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3086) for it.

Comment: Hoho! Here in 2016, this is actually causing problems. I don't know why, but some of my actionSubmits stopped working with recent browser updates. Adding this in seems to be fixing it. Thanks!

Comment: To be fair, I shouldn't still be using 2.2.0 in 2016, but here we are.

Comment: This workaround also works for `actionSubmitImage` (Grails 2.5.6).